# Jolt Transform: Single Value can't be added to an Array

Tags: json, jolt

I have the following Jolt Spec

```
 [
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "value": "[]"
      }
    }
   },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "values"
    }
   },
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "values": []
    }
   }
]
```

For the following Input:

```
[
  {
    "value": 175
  },
  {
    "value": 160
  }
]
```

I get the expected result as following:

```
{
  "values" : [ 175, 160 ]
}
```

And for the following Input:

```
[
  {
    "valueNum": 175
  }
]
```

I again get an expected result as follows:

```
{
  "values" : [ ]
}
```

But for the following input :

```
[
  {
    "value": 175
  }
]
```

I get the following output

```
{
  "values" : 175
}
```

I want to have the values in an array even if there is just one element in it like below:

```
{
   "values" : [175]
}
```

Could you please help me fixing my Jolt Spec to get the desired result? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just using a single **shift** transformation spec as the following one would suffice

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "&s[]"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

where **`&`** is a substitution for the key name(**`value`**), and **`s`** is a suffix to make the word plural

the ***demoes*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ are

[image]
[image]

Edit : If you need an output based on seperating the keys of the attributes to be **`value`** or the others(such as **`valueNum`**), then still a single spec like the one below would be sufficient :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "value": "&s[]",
        "*": "&[]"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

With the following spec, I was able to achieve all my use cases

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "value": "[]"
      }
    }
   },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "values[]"
    }
   },
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "values": []
    }
   }
]
```

Comment: Hi Abhinav, doesn't this seem to be verbose comparing the solution with only one spec..?

Comment: such as..? Can you add an extra input to the question which cannot be solved by this provided spec..?

Comment: Hi @BarbarosÖzhan, Thanks for the question. The Spec by you doesn't solve my problem because for any other JSON input than the following structure  [
  {
    "value": 175
  },
  {
    "value": 160
  }
], I want to have an output {
  "values" : [ ]
},   you can try with the inputs like {} , or [
  {
    "valueNum": 175
  }
]

Comment: You're welcome. OK, I was available to check my answer again just a few minutes, and edited . Can you check it out ...